# Работа с двумя объектами

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить значение свойства из второго объекта по "такому же ключу" из первого? Код здесь: http://pastebin.com/3BNyFqBz. Заранее спасибо.

```
var obj {
    'first': true,
    'second': false,
    'third': false,
    'fourth': true
};
var obj_2 {
    'first': false,
    'second': true,
    'third': true,
    'fourth': false
};
for(var i in obj) {
    if(obj[i] == true) {
        //...
        alert(obj_2[obj[i]]); //как получить значение свойства из второго объекта по "такому же ключу" из первого?
        //типа чтобы obj[i] стало какой-либо строкой (first или second), и можно было обращаться как obj_2['first']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(var i in obj) {
    alert(obj_2[i]);
}
```

Разве не так?

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i in obj) {
if(i == 'first') {

    alert(obj_2[i]); 

  }
}
```

Так вы получите свойства по тому же ключу что и во втором

Comment: А в цикле переменная, допустим i содержит индекс свойства или название?

Comment: в зависимости от того какой ключ вы указали, в вашем случае это ассоциативный объект с именованными ключами. Если бы был например такой  массив - `var obj = [1, 2, 3, 4]; ` то тогда ключом был бы порядковый номер элемента в массиве